# Add 3 event listeners to every row of a table

Tags: javascript, html-table, addeventlistener

First I create a container to store all rows. It's an array. Then I loop through every element of this array, and I would like to add event listener with event and function to them - but it does not work. Later I add the functions too. As a check I painted all rows pink.. and that worked. So the loop runs and the array of rows exists.

```
 <script>
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].addEventListener("onmouseover", mouseOver);
        rows[i].addEventListener("onmouseout", mouseOut);
        rows[i].addEventListener("click", mouseClick);
        rows[i].style.color="pink";  //testing the loop and the array - works
    }       
    function mouseOver() {
        document.getElementByTagNameId("tr").style.color = "red";
    }    
    function mouseOut() {
        document.getElementByTagNameId("tr").style.color = "black";
    }    
    function mouseClick(){  
       // nothing here yet
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: getElementByTagNameId is not a valid function; please have a look at the debug console. Use this.style.color instead

Comment: It looks like you're trying to give the rows colors based on hover/click/etc. This can be done in CSS and you would most likely be better off using that. Otherwise, @Pierre has the solution to the problem with your code.

Comment: @Pierre, thank you for your suggestion, I changed the function contents to this.style.color = "red".. etc.. but still not working...

Comment: maybe you are using IE which does not support addEventListener (it uses attachEvent), or there's another mistake elsewhere. However @Herohtar is right, CSS with :hover pseudo-class is much more easier !

Comment: @Herohtar thx for the TIP.. I'm experimenting right now to add event listener to a row of a table.. so then I will use CSS if you find that more meeting the standards...

Comment: @Pierre.. at the end I would like to identify the line that was clicked.. so that's why I was thinking on having an Array of <tr> objects.. the way of styling is secondary goal in my case...

Comment: I'm using Firefox. And also on Android... there Chrome. No IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the wrong event name. No "on" prefix can be used. Like no: onmouseover. Instead: mouseover event.

```
<script>
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
alert(rows.length); 
for (i=1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
    rows[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);
    rows[i].addEventListener("click", mouseClick);
    rows[i].style.color="pink";

}   

function mouseOver() {
    this.style.color = "red";
}

function mouseOut() {
    this.style.color = "black";
}

function mouseClick(){
    alert("Row was clicked!");
}
</script>
```